# Calling native executable from Yocto Makfile

Tags: makefile, yocto

I have a bb file than DEPENDS a package.  In my makefile I need to run an executable from that package.

Right now I do something like

SOAPCPP2          = ../../../x86_64-linux/gsoap-native/2.8.51-r0/build/gsoap/soapcpp2

$(SOAPCPP2)

Gotta be a more correct way, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DEPENDS` variable, if you are using an executable generated during the yocto build time you must include the name of the package. In your case I think you could use the `DEPENDS` like this:

`DEPENDS += " soapcpp2-native "`

The trick is in append the word `-native` after the name of the package.

Once is included, you can call directly the program without including the path of the system.

This should work, but depending on the Yocto version you maybe need the usage of DEPENDS on the specific docs of your version.